# Unable to start posgtresql, the reason isn't clear

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, postgresql

I've installed postgresql by pacman. Now I'm trying to run it:

```
    $ sudo systemctl start postgresql
    Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And then:

```
    $ sudo systemctl status postgresql
    ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-07-10 15:30:47 UTC; 17s ago
      Process: 19468 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jul 10 15:30:47 my_comp systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
    Jul 10 15:30:47 my_comp systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Jul 10 15:30:47 my_comp systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
    Jul 10 15:30:47 my_comp systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jul 10 15:30:47 my_comp systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Take a look at PostgreSQL's log files to see. It's a pity that the systemd output doesn't point to them, or that PostgreSQL on this system isn't configured to output its logs to systemd.

Comment: does this [archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=149446) link get you any closer?

Comment: @CraigRinger, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 26):

Following step solved your problem

step 1: create the data directory (acordingly  with the PGROOT variable set before in the config file)

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/postgres/data
```

Step 2: set /var/lib/postgres/data ownership to user 'postgres'

```
chown postgres /var/lib/postgres/data
```

Step 3: As user 'postgres' start the database.

```
sudo -i -u postgres
initdb  -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'
```

Step 4: Start the service as root

Comment: Depending on version, this may need to be `initdb -D '/var/lib/pgsql/data'`

Comment: If you had a few databases, this will create fresh Postgresql server without old databases!

Comment: step4: how to start the service in root?

Comment: yes. it worked. by logged in using ```sudo -i -u postgres``` start service using ```pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data -l logfile start```

Comment: This does start the database successfully, but when I run `systemctl status postgresql.service`, I still get the same error  as provided by OP. What is happening here?

Comment: Fedora, for Fedora 34+ (where XX is the version of PG 14 or15 and possibly higher) with PG is "/var/lib/pgsql/XX/data"
or "/var/lib/pgsql/data" for 13 and probably lower
Also, -D will make a new database, so be careful if you already have one... there will be a prompt if you do, but still ;)

Answer (score 5):

run these commands as said on `/usr/share/doc/postgresql/README.rpm-dist` as root user

```bsh
postgresql-setup --initdb
systemctl restart postgresql.service
systemctl enable postgresql.service
```

Comment: postgresql-setup: command not found

Comment: This worked for me in a current and up-to-date RHEL 8.5 server.

Answer (score 0):

The logging you shared includes this line:

```
/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What is `$PGROOT` set to? Does `$PGROOT/data` exist? Does this directory have any files init? If not, you may need to run [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-initdb.html) on the directory.

To initialize, create an empty data directory as root, then use chown to assign ownership of that directory to the database user account, then su to become the database user to run `initdb /path/to/data`.

Answer (score 0):

After **setting a password** for the `postgres` user:

```
$ sudo passwd postgres
```

run the following command:

```
$ su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
```

Comment: -bash: initdb: command not found